# InstallShield 2015 Error 1606 only when connected to a network

Tags: installshield, installshield-2015

I've made an installer with InstallShield 2015 and when I attempt to run the setup it gets to the part where it says calculating space requirements, pauses for a few seconds, then pops up an error box with the message:

"Error 1606. Could not access network location install."
with a retry and cancel button.

Clicking the cancel button causes the same error message to display with just an OK button.

If I unplug the network cable I no longer get the errors and it installs the program perfectly.

This is happening on multiple PCs on the same network. I cant try on a different network at the moment.

I've looked for this error all over google, but all responses seem to be tailored towards people getting this error while installing random software, not people getting this error in an installer they've made.

Regardless I've tried most of the solutions suggested, mostly registry edits, none of which have helped.

EDIT:
I contacted InstallShield to get assistance from them. They say it's the same thing as everywhere on the internet. Change your registry entries.

This is not fixing it for me and I've tried the installer on different PCs and networks and the same issue happens there. I've tried changing the registry keys they suggested I change, and I've changed everything I could find on google to the recommended values.

As requested here's the section of the log file where the error occurs (when connected to a network):

```
MSI (c) (74:80) [10:25:44:818]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLDIR.8B221063_CD84_419E_90B4_CAFEF7A11EEB property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\Your Company Name\Default\'.
MSI (c) (74:80) [10:25:44:818]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ISMyCompanyDir property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\My Company Name\'.
MSI (c) (74:80) [10:25:44:818]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ISMyProductDir property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\My Company Name\My Product Name\'.
MSI (c) (74:80) [10:25:44:818]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding GlobalAssemblyCache property. Its value is 'E:\'.
MSI (c) (74:80) [10:26:08:861]: Note: 1: 1314 2: Install 
MSI (c) (74:80) [10:26:08:861]: Note: 1: 1606 2: Install 
Error 1606.Could not access network location Install.
MSI (c) (74:80) [10:26:34:146]: Product: FakeProductNamesRUs Full Update V3.1.4.2 -- Error 1606.Could not access network location Install.

MSI (c) (74:80) [10:26:34:146]: Note: 1: 1606 2: Install 
Error 1606.Could not access network location Install.
MSI (c) (74:80) [10:26:35:066]: Product: FakeProductNamesRUs Full Update V3.1.4.2 -- Error 1606.Could not access network location Install.

Action ended 10:26:35: CostFinalize. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (74:80) [10:26:35:066]: Doing action: SetupCompleteError
Action 10:26:35: SetupCompleteError.
```

The same section in the successful install (when not connected to a network):

```
MSI (c) (30:80) [10:44:55:889]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DIR25.8B221063_CD84_419E_90B4_CAFEF7A11EEB property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\Your Company Name\'.
MSI (c) (30:80) [10:44:55:889]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLDIR.8B221063_CD84_419E_90B4_CAFEF7A11EEB property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\Your Company Name\Default\'.
MSI (c) (30:80) [10:44:55:889]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ISMyCompanyDir property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\My Company Name\'.
MSI (c) (30:80) [10:44:55:889]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ISMyProductDir property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\My Company Name\My Product Name\'.
MSI (c) (30:80) [10:44:55:889]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding GlobalAssemblyCache property. Its value is 'E:\'.
MSI (c) (30:80) [10:44:55:890]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying DIRPROPERTY2 property. Its current value is 'Install'. Its new value: 'Install\'.
MSI (c) (30:80) [10:44:55:890]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DIRPROPERTY1 property. Its value is 'E:\'.
MSI (c) (30:80) [10:44:55:890]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding FakeProductNamesRUs property. Its value is 'E:\FakeProductNamesRUs\'.
MSI (c) (30:80) [10:44:55:890]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ISCommonFilesFolder property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\InstallShield\'.
```

The E Drive mentioned in the log is the system reserved partition.

I'm saddened by the lack of support from InstallShield, but they insist that the issue is caused by an environment issue even though it happens on multiple PCs and multiple networks and their only 'solution' doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Does a verbose log give any more details on what it can't access and help you understand why it's trying or why it fails? The multiple account contexts due to UAC can make things like this more difficult to diagnose, but it's hard to tell why it's trying to use the network drive at all given what you've described.

Comment: I've added the section of the log where it fails

Comment: I think we need a bit more in the failing log - where does "Install" come from (assuming that's not a redacted value)? Note that it differs from DRIPROPERTY2's value of "Install\" (presumably because it was able to find the folder). See [Windows Installer Error Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372835) to decode the 1314 and 1606. Since it's just a matter of not finding it, perhaps Process Monitor can help tell what it *is* doing. Can you safely remove DIRPROPERTY2 from your project (either property or directory)?